# Struts 1.x validate() and validation.xml

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-validation

I am using the validations framework with Struts 1.x, and have some validations declared in `validation.xml`.

I needed some more complex validation, so I also overrode the `validate()` method in the form.

It turns out, overriding the `validate()` method cancels out use of `validation.xml`. Is this true?

Can `validate()` and `validation.xml` coexist on the same action form?

Answer (score 1):

It will cancel the struts validation if you override the `validate` method and not call the `super.validate(mapping, request)`. Do it in your code to coexist the custom validation through `validate` method and framework validation via `validation.xml`.