# ValidateForm class in Struts 1.X

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1, struts-validation

Using the `ValidateForm` from Struts 1, we will be able to validate the FORM used in the Struts,
I went through number of links (https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/103.html) still not able to figure the **functionality of `super.validate()` method in Struts**

**Default Validation  (using `super.validate()` in Struts):**

```
public class RegistrationForm extends org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm {
// private variables for registration form
private String name;
private String email;
...

public RegistrationForm() {
super();
}

public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
ActionErrors errors = super.validate(mapping, request);
if (errors == null) {
    errors = new ActionErrors();
}
return errors;
}
// getter and setter methods for private variables
}
```

In the above code what is the significance of `super.validate()` method, What is the validation does it perform? Could someone explain this please!

Answer (score 0):

It performs validation of request parameters according to the rules defined in `validation.xml`. It provides the basic validation and if you want to use a custom validation then you should override its `validate()` method.  Here's the description of the method:

> Validate the properties that have been set from this HTTP request, and return an `ActionErrors` object that encapsulates any validation errors that have been found.  If no errors are found, return `null` or an `ActionErrors` object with no recorded error messages.

[What happens if you override `validate()` and not calling `super.validate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15299566/573032):

> It will cancel the Struts validation if you override the validate method and not call the `super.validate(mapping, request)`. Do it in your code to coexist the custom validation through `validate()` method and framework validation via `validation.xml`.